# Getting font size from excel spreadsheet using Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I'm trying to get the font size of the header on an excel spreadsheet but I haven't been able to get it. I tried using the following to get the size but I haven't been able to get the size. None of the following worked for me because it doesn't return the correct font size.
headerFont.getFontHeight ();
headerFont.getFontHeightInPoints ();
Any suggestion?

Below is the code that I have:

```
    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);

        int numRows = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
        int numCols = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();

        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
                headerFontFamily = headerFont.getFontName();
                headerFont.getFontHeight();
                headerFont.getFontHeightInPoints();

            }
        }
        file.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the fonts from the cells. Fonts are part of the cell styles. Cell styles can be got via `Cell.getCellStyle`. Then the index of the used font can be got as a `short` via `CelStyle.getFontIndex` or as `int` via `CelStyle.getFontIndexAsInt` or as `int` via  `CelStyle.getFontIndex` dependig of `apache poi` version used. The latter works using current `5.0.0` version.

Complete example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ReadExcel {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelExample.xlsx"));
  FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();  
 
  DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
  
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    String value = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
    System.out.println(value);
    CellStyle style = cell.getCellStyle();
    //short fontIdx = style.getFontIndex(); // depends on apache poi version
    //int fontIdx = style.getFontIndexAsInt(); // depends on apache poi version
    int fontIdx = style.getFontIndex(); // depends on apache poi version
    Font font = workbook.getFontAt(fontIdx);
    System.out.println(font.getFontName() + ", " + font.getFontHeightInPoints());
   }
  }
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Note: This only works if the cell only has one font. If the cell contains rich text strings, then there are fonts for each formatting text run. Then `RichTextString` needs to be got and traversed. This is much more complex and needs to be done different for `HSSF` and `XSSF`.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get the size with your help!